# Backing field vs "value" keyword in property setter

Tags: c#, properties, micro-optimization, backing-field

I have a property with a backing field and some logic inside the setter. I wonder whether I should use the `value` keyword or the backing field.

**Option 1:**

```
private bool _backingField;
public bool MyProperty
{
    get => _backingField;
    set
    {
        _backingField = value;
        if(value) // <--
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
private bool _backingField;
public bool MyProperty
{
    get => _backingField;
    set
    {
        _backingField = value;
        if(_backingField) // <--
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which of them has better performance? Tests I have run on my machine showed no significant difference, but I am not sure my machine is enough to get the whole picture.

**Note:** I do realize this is probably taking micro-optimization to a whole new level of ridiculousness, but I am still curious to know if there is a definitive answer.

---

**Edit:** This question is not opinion-based, since I am asking if there is an **objective** difference.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a difference.

Comment: So are you asking if reading a variable or another makes a measurable difference? No I think not.

Comment: @Steve - Not all variables are created equal.

Comment: *"whole new level of ridiculousness"* - it's good you understand that ;). My 5 cents: in multithreading scenario using `value` is preferable, but performance is silly criteria.

Comment: @Sinatr - Why? What would be the consequences of using the backing field in a multithreading scenario?

Comment: I do not know who voted to close this question on an "opinion-based question" base, but I am asking if there is an ***objective*** difference that I am not noticing.

Comment: @Sipo, why? Because `value` is a parameter, field access have to be synchronized.  Reading field may return another value than you just set.

Comment: Goto disassembly and compare translation to be sure if there is any difference or not (may differ in release/debug build too) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the IL generated with `if(value)` in Release mode:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_MyProperty(bool 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      bool ConsoleApp1.Program::_backingField
  IL_0007:  ldarg.1
  IL_0008:  brfalse.s  IL_0014
  IL_000a:  ldstr      "true"
  IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0014:  ret
} // end of method Program::set_MyProperty
```

Note that I've added `Console.WriteLine("true");` to the body of the `if` to prevent it to be removed by the compiler.

Now the IL with `if (_backingField)`:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_MyProperty(bool 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      bool ConsoleApp1.Program::_backingField
  IL_0007:  ldarg.0
  IL_0008:  ldfld      bool ConsoleApp1.Program::_backingField
  IL_000d:  brfalse.s  IL_0019
  IL_000f:  ldstr      "true"
  IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method Program::set_MyProperty
```

The only difference is the additional call to `ldfld bool ConsoleApp1.Program::_backingField` in the second version, so in theory it should be a tick slower. However, that tick should be negligible small.